# ReactJS frustrating element.scrollTop bug

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scrolltop

I have this frustrating problem with scroll in my ReactJS and TailwindCSS project. I was trying to show element when viewport is on specific part of my website and to hide it when it's not.

```
function App() {
  const scrollRef = createRef()
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    let heightToShow = 1000;
    const winScroll = document.querySelector('.App').scrollTop; 
    if (winScroll > heightToShow) {
      setIsVisible(true);
    } else {
      setIsVisible(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div onScroll={handleScroll} className="App scroll-smooth relative bg-secondary h-screen snap-y snap-mandatory overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll flex flex-col">
      <div ref={scrollRef} />
      <Header />
      <About />
      <Skills />
      <Projects />
      <Contacts />
      <TopButton isVisible={isVisible} ref={scrollRef} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

At first, i've tried using `window.pageYOffset` which didn't work, because the value always stayed at 0 and element didn't show up. With `document.querySelector('.App').scrollTop` I made the functionality work as needed, but I got this terrible bug, where if `winScroll`'s value gets to `heightToShow`'s value - my viewport jumps back to the original `winScroll`'s value. So basically, It is almost impossible to scroll both ways with mousewheel past my `heightToShow` value.

Any thoughts on why it is happening?

Comment: I deleted my answer because `useEffect` won't fire on a mutating object... So my answer is totally wrong ;) - Could you create a [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io) with your issue reproduced?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette it's a shame you've deleted it, because it was almost right, I only have changed `scrollTopPos` to be a `state` and  used `setState` in `handleScroll`. Now it works, so thank you :) If you post your answer again with these changes - I will mark it as correct and upvote it.

Comment: Thanks Rey... But I think the best would be that you post an answer with the details about how you fixed the issue. That will be more helpful to future readers to have an exact solution. ;)